# Receiving coming from a stored procedure data in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Create a stored procedure in mysql. Using CodeIgniter 3 already configured to use the mysqli driver, I tried to receive the data returned by the SP but did not get success.
SP:

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_DadosRelatorio`(IN ano INT, IN mes INT, IN retirada INT, IN produto INT, 
OUT d1 INT)
BEGIN
 SELECT 
    ifnull(sum(qtde),0) INTO d1
FROM
    saida_produto 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM data_saida) = ano
     and
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM data_saida) = mes
    and
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM data_saida) = 1
    and tipo_retirada = retirada
    and id_produto = produto;
```

I made the call in CI 3:
$query = $this->db->query("call SP_DadosRelatorio(2016,1,1,1,@d1"));

call the function $query->result(); I got the following message:

```
> > object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)[51]   public 'conn_id' => 
>     object(mysqli)[18]
>       public 'affected_rows' => null
>       public 'client_info' => null
>       public 'client_version' => null
>       public 'connect_errno' => null
>       public 'connect_error' => null
>       public 'errno' => null
>       public 'error' => null
>       public 'error_list' => null
>       public 'field_count' => null
>       public 'host_info' => null
>       public 'info' => null
>       public 'insert_id' => null
>       public 'server_info' => null
>       public 'server_version' => null
>       public 'stat' => null
>       public 'sqlstate' => null
>       public 'protocol_version' => null
>       public 'thread_id' => null
>       public 'warning_count' => null   public 'result_id' => boolean true   public 'result_array' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty   public 'result_object' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty   public 'custom_result_object' => 
>     array (size=0)
>       empty   public 'current_row' => int 0   public 'num_rows' => null   public 'row_data' => null
```

How do I access the value of @ d1 coming from mysql database via stored procedure in IC3?

when i try execute $query->result();
The PHP show me:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_result.php
```

Comment: make it as function and use usual select

Comment: in this case i will need return 3 results. In a function , how i can make this? if was a store procedure i could make in this way: SP(IN a INT, IN b INT, @d1 ,@d2 ,@d3).
But how make this in a function?

Comment: The way CI3 works is that it returns true in "result_id" on successful commands like UPDATE and DELETE, false on unsuccessful executions and result on SELECT queries. fetch_object() is called on the "result_id", if it's boolean error is encountered. Check your SQL syntax. Make sure your query returns a actual data.